# Best way to find a string pattern and replace a character in between that pattern in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a String

```
Thi__(1)__s i__(2)__s a test__(5)__ mess__(4)__age __(6)__
```

I want to replace the numbers in between the pattern `__()__` by that number-1, that is, 2 with 1, 3 with 2 and so on. And there is a condition, that number should be greater than 3.

So my final string will look like

```
Thi__(1)__s i__(2)__s a test__(4)__ mess__(3)__age __(5)__
```

I know how to make a logic for that but as I am new to Javascript/Jquery I am looking for a better way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried.

Comment: combinaison of regex and logic test maybe ?

Comment: I was first fetching all the patterns, Modify them, storing it in a list and then replacing them 1 by 1 in the string. Such a noob I am :-|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = "Thi__(1)__s i__(2)__s a test__(5)__ mess__(4)__age __(6)__";

var replaced = str.replace(/(__\()(\d+)(\)__)/g, function(_, left, val, right){ //replace all (digits)
   val = +val; //convert to number
   return left + (val > 3 ? --val: val) + right; //use whatever convert logic you need
});
```

Comment: You should add the `__`s to your pattern.

Comment: @Bergi thx. Moar capturing groups added. :)

Comment: Thanks @Yuri. You saved me :). This is exactly what I wanted. I see you used regex there but I am still confused what that function is doing. Reply whenever you can :)

Comment: @KunalMawar The function takes all captured groups and combines them to return new substring that should be inserted instead of the matched one. `left` is '__ (', `val` is digits seq, `right` is ') __'.